# How do I return an error message to the client after failed Mongoose validation in Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a very basic POST route that creates a new user out of the given data.

Here's how I save it:

```
app.post('/create', function(req, res){
    var firstUser = new models.User(req.body);
    firstUser.save();
});
```

My Mongoose User schema has a few validation options, which work. If I pass the wrong data, validation fails and the user isn't created.

But there's a problem: Mongoose's save() function is asynchronous, so how do I let the client now the validation failed?

The post function will be done by then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a look at [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html). Because save method is asynchronous it takes a callback as parameter. This is where you should check for errors.

```
app.post('/create', function(req, res){
    var firstUser = new models.User(req.body);
    firstUser.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(500, { error: 'Saving first user failed!' });
        } else {
            res.send({ success: 'Saved!' }); 
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Ah, I thought once the post() function finished you weren't able to send anything to the client anymore.

Comment: In fact, it's the call to res.end() which end the function. res.send() add some stuff to the response, then it calls this function.

Comment: It's better to use next for handling errors since that's what it's there for. It will also put all your error handling in one middleware handler instead of repeating yourself all over your project.

Comment: @Pickels could you please add an answer that illustrates the use of next in this scenario?